# How to prove that the unit sphere $\Bbb S^1$ has Hausdorff dimension $1$?

Tags: measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

It should suffice that I get a hint; I would just like to know what particular characteristic of $\Bbb S^1$ makes it have a Hausdorff dimension $1$. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that the unit interval has Hausdorff dimension 1?

Comment: The justification is similar to that of the Hausdorff dimension of $\mathbb{R}$ that is 1. The d-dimensional Hausdorff content is equal to $0$ for $d\geq 1$, so when taking the infimum to calculate $dim_H$ you get $1$.

Comment: @Test123 I'm not quite sure how to prove that the $a-$dimensional Hausdorff content is $>0$ for $a < 1$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen no, but I'll give it a try.